# Define sequence and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Define function f: $\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $ by: $ f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{18}{x}}$

1) Show that $f'$ has one minimum/maximum, define $f'$s monotony conditions and sketch $f$.

I have this under control where i found $f'=\frac{x^3-27}{\sqrt{3}x^2\sqrt{\frac{x^3+54}{x}}} $

Where i put $f'=\frac{x^3-27}{\sqrt{3}x^2\sqrt{\frac{x^3+54}{x}}} =0$ and found out that $x=3$

To find the monotony conditions i put $x=2$ and $x=4$ into f' and found out that $x=2$ is negative and $x=4$ is positive. Which can then be concluded that f is decreasing towards the minimum 3 and rising after the minimum 3.

It's in the next subexercices i am having some difficulties

Now let $a (>0)\in \mathbb R$ and define the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty $ by:

$x_0=a \ \ \ and \ \ \ x_{n+1}=f(x_n) \ \ \ , \ \ \ n\geq 1$

2) Show that $x_n\geq 3$ for all $n\geq 1$

3) Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ (the sequence before minus $x_0$ is decreasing.

4) Show that the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent and find the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

2) follows from the fact that the minimum is $f(3)=3$

3) follows from the fact that $x> 3 \implies x > f(x)$.  i.e. show $\dfrac{x^2}3+\dfrac{18}x \le x^2$

4) follows from statements (2) and (3).

Comment: So since the sequence is decreasing and limited by 3, the limit of the sequence is 3?

Comment: @Christeferus we can conclude by decreasing and having a lower bound that it converges.  What exactly it converges to is not given just by those conditions.

Comment: Having shown the limit exists, you could argue that it must satisfy $L = \sqrt{L^2/3+18/L}$ and find it from there.